# how to move offscreen (sub window/menu) back to screen

Tags: windows-8, adobe-photoshop

Everyone explains very well and simple how to move an offscreen menu back to visible field of the monitor, but nobody tells how to move a submenu.

By submenu I mean something like when you open Photoshop, in my case Manga studio, and make a new file and the option window for new file opens up, but that one particular window is offscreen and I can not move it using normal moving methods used for the main programs.

Hope someone can solve this for me, thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that the window (the "New" window) is not bound to the width/height of the actuall application? And I assume in the task bar, the "New" window doesn't have it's own icon in the task bar? How many screens do you have?

Comment: Maybe he refers to an MDI? or just a Window with no titlebar?. too unclear.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to the off-screen application.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to bring up the system menu (you won't see it because it is off screen).
3. Press <kbd>R</kbd> to select the `Restore` menu choice to ensure the window isn't maximized (you can't move it if it's maximized).
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> again, then <kbd>M</kbd> to select the `Move` menu choice.
5. Press one of the arrow keys to initiate the movement.
6. Now just use the mouse to place the window where you want.